# ffmpeg shutting down when stream is silent

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, streaming, icecast

I am running ffmpeg in a Linux environment, where I merge the audio stream from an Icecast-stream and a static image in order to be able to stream that to Youtube.

At times, the Icecast stream get's very silent, sometimes for almost a minute. That is intended to happen, due to the nature of the content. But, when the stream get's too silent, ffmpeg just shuts down with no notice.

This is how I start ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 30  -s 1280x720 -i /var/www/html/files/youtube/image.png -i http://my-stream-to-icecast:8000/my-mount -c:v libx264 -preset fast -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my-youtube-key
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? And/or how to optimize the above?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry, please ignore this answer. It would apply if the stream would be sent back to an Icecast server, not Youtube.**

That is most likely due to Icecast's source timeout. If you use highly efficient codecs, then silence encodes to "nothing" and the icecast server will not get any data and disconnect the source.

You can confirm this by looking at the Icecast error.log

Depending on the codec you use you may be able to configure a minimum bitrate (the codec then inserts dummy data) or you'll need to inject low level noise into the audio side. One or two least significant bits is enough and not perceptible by humans, but will keep the encoder busy and the bitrate up.

Comment: ffmpeg is just streamcopying the audio so there's no audio encoder invoked. We don't know if whatever's feeding the icecast is under the OP's control.

Comment: Actually disregard my answer completely. As the target is not Icecast again, but YouTube. Must have missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try mixing it with a dummy stream:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 30 -i /var/www/html/files/youtube/image.png
 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 120 -i http://my-stream-to-icecast:8000/my-mount
 -f lavfi -i anullsrc
 -filter_complex "[1]aresample=async=1[i];[i][2]amix=2:shortest,volume=2[a]"
 -map 0:v -map "[a]"
 -c:v libx264 -s hd720  -preset fast -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p
 -c:a aac -shortest
 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my-youtube-key
```

I don't how the amix will handle it if the Icecast feed dies. You'll have to check.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but do only get this:

Unrecognized option 'reconnect_streamed'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

I am using v. 2.6.9. Any idea?

Comment: You need 3.0 or newer.

Comment: That solved the above issue, thanks. But I still have no luck in solving this:

[http @ 0x96e9320] Stream ends prematurely at 0, should be 18446744073709551615
http://my-stream-to-icecast:8000/my-mount: Input/output error

Any further thoughts?